# VIsual Studio Using custom template for new app and making it unique

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I exported my app project toa template in Visual Studio 2015 as I want to use the template for a new app, which is kind of the same but a different topic. Using the template is all fine and I can create the new app with the same code, but it has the same signiture of the app i used to make the template so it uninstalls that app when installing the new one based on the template.
How do i make the new app unique? I have changed the package details, and as much as i can think of but it still seems to think its the original app.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out it was quite simple in the end. The    in the Package.appxmanifest is what makes the app unique on the phone, or worldwide in the case of windows store.
So now, i have a nice template to bung out more apps :-)